# The review menu opens and immediately springs closed if clicked when logged out

Tags: bug, review, login, top-bar

I had a tab open in Firefox from when I was logged in. Not realizing I had been logged out of the site, I clicked the review icon in the top bar. The menu that would ordinarily show me the review queues that I am allowed to use appeared, but only for a fraction of a second. After a few tries, I managed to get a screenshot:

[image: An empty review menu as it appeared while springing open and shut again like an angry stapler that has developed consciousness.]

The icon was highlighted in white after the menu closed:

[image: The review menu icon highlighted in white, like an indentation on a table from slamming your hand down on a stapler in frustration about some totally unrelated argument with your boss moments before, and now your hand will ache for the rest of the day, and maybe Ms. Feldkarp was right, way back in the first grade, about how getting upset doesn't solve anything.]

When highlighted that way, I could not attempt to open the menu again, but clicking elsewhere on the page removed the highlighting on the icon and I was able to try again (only to have it close immediately again).

I do not expect to be able to review posts while not logged in, of course. But I didn't expect anything like this behavior. Usually if I try to do something that requires I be logged in--even from a page that loaded when I was logged in and doesn't "know" I'm logged out yet--I am either *(a)* told that I need to be logged in, or *(b)* told that I don't have the permissions to perform that action.

Since empty menus that open then immediately close without saying anything about what's not working is disconcerting, I doubt this is the intended behavior of the system.